# How to obtain/create/update service credentials on IBM push service

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

We created a push notification application service over a year ago, before there was a need for appGuid and client secret. However, now we need the client secret and app guid to work with a new application.

When we try to create the credentials, by using the dialog generated by 'New credential' button we end up getting null just like the image below.

[Image with null for credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLaJC.png)

Is there any way to update the credentials without needing to create a new service.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the dashboard opening when clicking on the push notification instance? If yes, are you able to view the Configure page with Mobile Options?

Comment: Yes, thanks seems like that was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Push notification app and navigate to Manage->Configure and click on Mobile options to obtain the appSecret, clientSecret and appGuid.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Neeraj comment, You can get to your credentials by going to your push notification instance, then clicking **manage** on the outer left panel, then click **Configure** on the inner left panel and finally click on the **Mobile options** button.